# Missing features after merge/append

Tags: arcpy, merge, esri-geodatabase

​I was trying to merge stream lines from many HUC polygons into one. Currently these stream lines are stored in one geodatabase as separate feature classes with each feature class corresponding to one HUC polygon. It's polyline feature and all lines have exactly the same attributes. All feature classes have the same schema.

I gave several tries by using arcpy.Merge_management() and arcpy_Append_management(), all ended up only merging several HUCs, but not all. (see the attached picture: try to merge stream lines from all green polygons, but only got stream lines from several upper polygons merged). I also tried to repair geometry first before merge, define extent before merge.., none of these seem to fix the issue.

Still new to python, anything I missed? I use ArcMap 10.7.1. Here is the code I tried:

```
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("D:/test.gdb")
arcpy.Merge_management(fcList, "D:/output.gdb/merged")

emptyFC="merged"
schemaType="NO_TEST"
fieldMapping=""
subtype=""
template="example"
spatial_reference=arcpy.Describe(template).spatialReference

has_m="DISABLED"
has_z="DISABLED"

try:
    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outWorkspace, emptyFC, "POLYLINE", template, has_m, has_z, spatial_reference)

    listFC=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("", "POLYLINE")
    arcpy.Append_management(listFC, outWorkspace+os.sep+emptyFC, schemaType, fieldMapping, subtype)

except Exception as err:
        print(err.args[0])
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should remove the try/except from the code that you are testing and presenting in case it’s masking an otherwise useful error message.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo, Tried without try/except, still the same issue. I am puzzled as every time it only merged that several polygons and I thought merge/append is common geoprocessing.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise the code that you are presenting and include the full message and line number of any error that you receive.  See tips on writing a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312).

Comment: Have you made sure all features get listed in `listFC` with `print(listFC)`? `"POLYLINE"` should be `"Polyline"` but I dont know if it matters. `print(outWorkspace+os.sep+emptyFC)`, what does it say? What is `outWorkspace`, a file geodatabase or a folder? Do you have basic/standard/advanced license? I think you cant merge unlimited number of features with basic

Comment: Thanks @BERA. yes, all features do exist and outWorkspace is a file geodatabase. I have the advanced license. Interestingly I tried to convert all feature classes into shapefiles, then merge individual shapefiles using the same code, now it looks stream lines from all polygons are merged. Nothing else was done, just convert feature class to shapefile. It seems to me that there are some differences when Merge_management()/Append_management() handling geodatabase and shapefile. I would appreciate any comment/insight and love to know why using geodatabase did not work.